# Launch Google Sign-In page in current tab/window

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth

Currently integrating Google's Sign-In for a website application. It's a responsive website that scales down nicely to work on mobile device browsers.

Rather than the Sign-In page launching in a new popup window I'd like it to launch in the current window/tab, especially because this would improve the UX on mobile devices where new windows are more troublesome to navigate between.

But I've read that in order to launch Sign-In within the same window I would need to integrate Google's more complex OAuth 2.0 authorization system, which I'd prefer to avoid due to its complexity and because the standard Sign-In system supplies everything the website app currently needs.

Can the OAuth2 route be avoided at all please?